# How to duplicate rows in a dataframe while changing value in one variable in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence

My data looks something like this, but with many more rows and banks. Row 1 reads: at bank1, transactions from $0-25 are charged a fee of $0.10.

| name | min_value | max_value | fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bank1 | 0 | 25 | 0.10 |
| bank1 | 25 | 50 | 0.20 |
| bank2 | 0 | 15 | 0.05 |
| bank2 | 15 | 25 | 0.10 |

I want to have more rows of bank1 and bank2 where min_value ranges from 0-25 at intervals of 0.1 while keeping all other variable values constant. So, my ideal table looks like this:

| name | min_value | max_value | fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bank1 | 0 | 25 | 0.10 |
| bank1 | 0.1 | 25 | 0.10 |
| bank1 | 0.2 | 25 | 0.10 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| bank1 | 25 | 25 | 0.10 |
| bank1 | 25 | 50 | 0.20 |
| bank1 | 25.1 | 50 | 0.20 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| bank1 | 50 | 50 | 0.20 |
| bank2 | 0 | 15 | 0.05 |
| bank2 | 0.1 | 15 | 0.05 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| bank2 | 15 | 15 | 0.05 |
| bank2 | 15 | 25 | 0.10 |

and so on.

Please help. Code for the table shown here is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("bank1", "bank1", "bank2", "bank2"),
  min_value = c(0, 25, 0, 15),
  max_value = c(25, 50, 15, 25),
  fee = c(0.10, 0.20, 0.05, 0.10))
```

Thanks so much in advance!

I tried using predict(), seq(), creating an empty dataframe and running a loop where all other variable values are drawn from the initial dataframe but min_value is expanded using seq(), but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `unnest` like below

```
df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(min_value = list(seq(min_value, max_value, by = 0.1))) %>%
    unnest(min_value)
```

or

```
df %>%
    mutate(min_value = Map(seq, min_value, max_value, by = 0.1)) %>%
    unnest(min_value)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 754 × 4
   name  min_value max_value   fee
   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 bank1       0          25   0.1
 2 bank1       0.1        25   0.1
 3 bank1       0.2        25   0.1
 4 bank1       0.3        25   0.1
 5 bank1       0.4        25   0.1
 6 bank1       0.5        25   0.1
 7 bank1       0.6        25   0.1
 8 bank1       0.7        25   0.1
 9 bank1       0.8        25   0.1
10 bank1       0.9        25   0.1
# ℹ 744 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I slightly adjust your code to avoid `tidyr::unnest()`: `df %>% rowwise(everything()) %>% reframe(min_value = seq(min_value, max_value, by = 0.1))`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(min_value, max_value), names_to = "min_max") %>%
  group_by(name, fee) %>%
  expand(value = full_seq(value, 0.1)) %>% 
  left_join(select(df, -min_value)) 

# A tibble: 754 × 4
# Groups:   name, fee [4]
   name    fee value max_value
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 bank1   0.1   0          25
 2 bank1   0.1   0.1        25
 3 bank1   0.1   0.2        25
 4 bank1   0.1   0.3        25
 5 bank1   0.1   0.4        25
 6 bank1   0.1   0.5        25
 7 bank1   0.1   0.6        25
 8 bank1   0.1   0.7        25
 9 bank1   0.1   0.8        25
10 bank1   0.1   0.9        25
# ℹ 744 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution with `by()`:

```r
by(df, seq_len(nrow(df)), \(x) {
  as.list(x) |>
    modifyList(list(min_value = seq(x$min_value, x$max_value, 0.1))) |>
    as.data.frame()
  }) |>
  do.call(what = rbind)

#       name min_value max_value fee
# 1.1  bank1       0.0        25 0.1
# 1.2  bank1       0.1        25 0.1
# 1.3  bank1       0.2        25 0.1
# 1.4  bank1       0.3        25 0.1
# 1.5  bank1       0.4        25 0.1
# 1.6  bank1       0.5        25 0.1
# 1.7  bank1       0.6        25 0.1
# 1.8  bank1       0.7        25 0.1
# 1.9  bank1       0.8        25 0.1
# 1.10 bank1       0.9        25 0.1
#  [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 744 rows ]
```

Answer (score 0):

An ugly (but potentially quick) variant with `data.table`:

```r
library("data.table")
df <- data.table(df)
df <- df[, cbind(.SD, min_value = seq(from = min_value, to = max_value, by = 0.1)),
         by = seq_len(nrow(df)), .SDcols = c("name", "max_value", "fee")]
df[, seq_len := NULL]

df
#>       name max_value fee min_value
#>   1: bank1        25 0.1       0.0
#>   2: bank1        25 0.1       0.1
#>   3: bank1        25 0.1       0.2
#>   4: bank1        25 0.1       0.3
#>   5: bank1        25 0.1       0.4
#>  ---                              
#> 750: bank2        25 0.1      24.6
#> 751: bank2        25 0.1      24.7
#> 752: bank2        25 0.1      24.8
#> 753: bank2        25 0.1      24.9
#> 754: bank2        25 0.1      25.0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>